# My_sine: what is wrong with my function?

Tags: c

Okay, so I have tried everything I could think of and haven't been able to figure out how to get this program working. I have tested all the functions used in the main, but included them anyway just in case there is some bug in them. More than likely though, I believe my mistake is in the main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265359

double int_power(double x, int e);


int main()
{
    int my_factorial(int n);
    double my_sine_taylor(double x);
    double my_sine(double x);
    double mod_two_pi(double x);
    double get_double(void);
    void safeGetString(char arr[], int limit)

    char arr[255];
    double x,y,ans;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    safeGetString(arr[255],255);
    my_sine(mod_two_pi(get_double()));
    printf("The sine is %f \n", ans);

    return 0;
}

/*
int_power should compute x^e, where x is a double and e is an integer.
*/
double int_power(double x, int e)
{
    int i = 0;
    double ans = 1;
    while(i <= e)
    {
        ans = ans*x;
        i++;
    }

    return ans;
}

/*
my_factorial will find the factorial of n
*/
int my_factorial(int n)
{
    int i = n;
    int ans = 1;

    while(i > 0)
    {
        ans = ans*i;
        i = i-1;
    }

    return ans;
}

/*
my_sine_taylor computes the approxmiation
of sin(x) using the taylor series up through x^11/11!
*/
double my_sine_taylor(double x)
{
    return x - int_power(x,3)/my_factorial(3) + int_power(x,5)/my_factorial(5) - 
    int_power(x,7)/my_factorial(7) + int_power(x,9)/my_factorial(9) - 
    int_power(x,11)/my_factorial(11);
}

/*
my_sine(x) should return a very good approximation of sin(x).
It should first reduce x mod 2pi and then map the result into the
upper right quadrant (where the taylor approximation is quite accurate).
Finally, it should use my_sine_taylor to compute the answer.
*/

double my_sine(double x)
{
    double ans;

    if (x >= 0 && x <= PI/2){
        ans = my_sine_taylor(x);
    } else if (x > PI/2 && x <= PI){
        x=PI-x;
        ans = my_sine_taylor(x);
    } else if (x > PI && x <= 3*(PI/2)){
        x = x-PI;
        ans = -(my_sine_taylor(x));
    } else {
        x=2*PI-x;
        ans = -(my_sine_taylor(x));
    }
}

/*
mod_two_pi(x) should return the remainder when x
is divided by 2*pi.  This reduces values like
17pi/2 down to pi/2
*/
double mod_two_pi(double x)
{
    int y;
    y = floor(x/(2*PI));
    x = x - 2*PI*y;
    return x;
}

/*
get_double and safeGetString are used to get floating point
input from the user
*/
double get_double(void)
{
    double x;
    char arr[255];
    x=atof(arr);
}

void safeGetString(char arr[], int limit)
{
    int c, i;
    i = 0;

    c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n'){
        if (i < limit -1){
            arr[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        c = getchar();
    }
    arr[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Try doing some debugging, then come back with a more specific question, and you'll likely get more help.  A quick tip - passing `arr[255]` to `safeGetString` looks wrong.

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and press CTRL+K.

Comment: There are also two `main` functions. Something is fishy here.

Comment: Please remove the blank line in between every other line in this program.

Comment: Why are you declaring functions *inside* your (first!) main?

Comment: by replacing the arr[255] with "input", i have enabled my program to run. however, it is still not working properly: when I give 2 as the input, the program spits out that the answer is 512181114...901(obscene number of zeros).000

Comment: @KennyTM what is it that you see wrong with the int_power function? I have tried running it and it keeps returning 0

Comment: @Domenic: I handled that for him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

oh my... where to begin?

Let's see...

---

You have this function:

```
double get_double(void)
{

    double x;

    char arr[255];

    x=atof(arr);
}
```

Which you call like this:

```
my_sine(mod_two_pi(get_double()));
```

So you're not sending it anything, but you're expecting to get some meaningful value.  Basically, `arr[255]` is not initialized, so it holds garbage. You're taking this garbage and converting it to a float with `atof`, but that doesn't do anything.

**If I had to guess, I'd say that this is what's really breaking your program.** The rest of what I wrote below is just commentary.

---

For some reason, you're declaring all of these functions **inside** your `main`.  I don't think this should *break* anything, but it sure is bad coding style.

---

`my_sine_taylor` calculates using a 6-element taylor approximation of the sine.  Are you sure you need that accuracy?  `11!` is pretty large, and certain numbers to the 11th power can also be pretty large.  You may be introducing unnecessary rounding or overflow errors with this.

Comment: Why is declaring functions bad coding style? Limiting the scope of declarations doesn't necessarily seem like a bad idea. Of course this one is definitely not right: `void safeGetString(char arr[], int limit) char arr[255];` .

Comment: declaring functions is a good idea. declaring them inside the function is generally not. it limits where the function may be used unnecessarily.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman: it doesn't limit where they can be used, it only limits where the compiler knows the prototype.  The functions can still be used anywhere in the scope where they are defined (i.e. in this case global) but the compiler will make (possibly dangerous) assumptions about the parameters and return type. Therein lies the reason why they should be declared near the top of the scope where they are visible.

Comment: I should have said "limits where the function may be **safely** used"

Comment: in actuality, my main function is not in my program to the very end (so the functions are not actually declared in the main). The reason that they are here are because 1.) i wanted to have the main written up at the top so anyone looking here could quickly see the main, and 2.)i have a bad teacher who taught me that that is the only way to do it

Comment: as for calling to the 11th power, that is the intended accuracy of the program (it was one of the constraints given to me for the assignment). it very well may be that this is what is ruining me, but it is something that i am not allowed to do away with and will simply have to compensate for.